# Lualatex buffer overflow

Tags: luatex, compilation-error

I want to compile one document on two different computers: one with Ubuntu 16 and `lualatex 0.8.0.0`, and another with Ubuntu 18 and `lualatex 1.0.4` 
On the first computer I got an error:

```
!LuaTeX error: buffer overflow: 1027 > 1024 at file ../../../texk/web2c/luatexdir/pdf/pdfgen.w, line 1434
```

It caused by too long image filename. This error can be fixed by reducing image filename.

But on the second computer everything is ok.

How this error can be fixed for `lualatex 0.8.0.0`?

Comment: Well if I got your description right it has been fixed in newer luatex version. So why don't you update the older system?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it's a decision for the last option. But I thought there are may some ways to solve the problem without updating TexLive or Ubuntu

Comment: Which one? It looks like a problem with the binary, so the binary must be changed. Beside this: luatex 0.8 is really very old and you will run probably in more problems with it.

Comment: even luatex 1.04 is old (and likely incompatible with current luatex packages) the current released version (miktex/texlive) is 1.10.0, unlike pdftex there were a lot of changes and especially beta releases prior to 1.0 shouldn't be used now